# UITableView with Hierarchical Categories -Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uicollectionview, datamodel

I have 3 categories:

1. Sneakers
2. Pants
3. Shirts

Each category can have a number of different name brands eg.

1.Sneakers > Nikes, Adidas, Reeboks

2.Pants > Lees, Levi's

3.Shirts > Ralph Lauren, Abercrombie

My users pick from a category and then they can add as many name brands as they want to it. After they've chosen the category and put whatever brand names they want, I need 2 tableViews (or collectionViews). The first tableView should show the category they picked and the 2nd tableview should show the brands they named in that category.

My problem is sorting by category. I know how to display all of the names they choose, but not the categories leading to the names.

The issue I'm having is if a user choose the Shirts category twice, the tableView to display it displays the shirt category twice, when it should only display it once.

I found [this](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewAndDataModel/TableViewAndDataModel.html) from Apple but it doesn't show the examples in Swift.

Any similar StackOverflow q/a's in Swift are fine as an answer.

Comment: So after they update the category, you are saying the Shirt is showing twice, which means your array containing category, contains Shirt twice, right? if so, use NSOrderedSet to remove the duplicate. Hope it helps

Comment: @Janmenjaya I've never used it before but I'll try it and let you know. Thanks!

Comment: I have updated the answer, check it to see the use of NSOrederedSet, to remove duplicate.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array contains duplicate in category.
I hope it must be containing duplicate, as you can see the duplicate in table view, so use the `NSOrderedSet` to remove duplicate.

Here is the demo code demonstrating use of `NSOrderedSet`

**Objective C Version:**

```
NSArray *category = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Sneakers", @"Pants", @"Shirts",@"Pants", @"Shirts", nil];

NSLog(@"Before using ordered set : %@", category.description);

// iOS 5.0 and later
NSArray * newCategoryArray = [[NSOrderedSet orderedSetWithArray:category] array];

NSLog(@"After using ordered set  : %@", newCategoryArray.description);
```

**Swift Version :**

```
let category = ["Sneakers", "Pants", "Shirts","Pants", "Shirts"];
NSLog("Before using ordered set : %@", category.description);

let newCategoryArray = NSOrderedSet(array: category).array;

NSLog("After using ordered set  : %@", newCategoryArray.description);
```

**Output :**

```
Before using ordered set : (
    Sneakers,
    Pants,
    Shirts,
    Pants,
    Shirts
)

After using ordered set  : (
    Sneakers,
    Pants,
    Shirts
)
```

Happy coding ...

Comment: i couldn't find the equivalent method in swift

Comment: @LanceSamaria, I have added the Swift equivalent code. Check the answer and let me know.

Comment: @thanks I'll try it in a few. I'm about to post a more detailed explantation of what I'm looking for. I'm not sure if your method will work with it but I will try it. Here's the link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39663089/uitableview-category-array-drill-down-swift-ios